# Why is it possible to have multiples addresses in an output of a transaction?

Tags: transactions, address

I am trying to load the blockchain into a MySQL database by using the data gathered from RPC calls to bitcoind. I am wondering why the `addresses` key within the `vout` array of a transaction is plural. Why can there be multiple addresses receiving bitcoins using only a single output? Below is the result of running

> bitcoind getrawtransaction 40d9e9dc25f89b590a26c486c46df9d40a72200080200c8fdf1bdf0562b2fba7 1

for some arbitrary transaction with hash `40d9e9dc25f89b590a26c486c46df9d40a72200080200c8fdf1bdf0562b2fba7`. If you look at the bottom you'll see the transaction's `vout` array with two outputs. The addresses values for each of those outputs are `127W9E5BVn6KxVCV2iiVbJmQrVoUd8xmu3` and `18AQDxusBQTJiNSG6EszPUfi85RhDpo7Qf` respectively. Is there some future plan by the core developers to allow multiple addresses to receive bitcoins from a single output? As you can see I am confused by the use of the plural here.

```
{
    "hex": "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",
    "txid": "40d9e9dc25f89b590a26c486c46df9d40a72200080200c8fdf1bdf0562b2fba7",
    "version": 1,
    "locktime": 0,
    "vin": [
        {
            "txid": "10e0c137837b4bf17aef987fd01cfc0040caf9e8081a996a99ae0fc79dbccdf5",
            "vout": 87,
            "scriptSig": {
                "asm": "304402206104041c8f9330103a1c3b77714b95e61ec90769b7f54cba426baaf8e676256402204134829de0e0ac24f340a680655b35747fbad26ab517d5324a22e20505130ba801 04ec3619fb20e737d551489c16b2df50bf91fb95b1d7b15a7835f752b9aeb5bcb4337c40aef04e39962c95e1a8630c793c158ee464d93a80b14cfb0ce9f8039d25",
                "hex": "47304402206104041c8f9330103a1c3b77714b95e61ec90769b7f54cba426baaf8e676256402204134829de0e0ac24f340a680655b35747fbad26ab517d5324a22e20505130ba8014104ec3619fb20e737d551489c16b2df50bf91fb95b1d7b15a7835f752b9aeb5bcb4337c40aef04e39962c95e1a8630c793c158ee464d93a80b14cfb0ce9f8039d25"
            },
            "sequence": 4294967295
        },
        {
            "txid": "6e1ccdef5c271ba24f5a5c30a3debd3a6c257a448911d84e4956f65045483802",
            "vout": 0,
            "scriptSig": {
                "asm": "304502210092bd8b04c5df3c23e9bf3516c1434ff4cdde8aff42d14ec18eea16393de900ad022008a005f46fdee01c17032fc3688af311c8413ca2c866e8bc95f6c4e95581669701 04d1a7f146aa464889c80286b105739bdfe05c186d4d1bc0737898f28d4e1c17a99d5a3c71ada20873916d0d5d75a92db2aaab37b8a14a18338b7b223727f5d417",
                "hex": "48304502210092bd8b04c5df3c23e9bf3516c1434ff4cdde8aff42d14ec18eea16393de900ad022008a005f46fdee01c17032fc3688af311c8413ca2c866e8bc95f6c4e955816697014104d1a7f146aa464889c80286b105739bdfe05c186d4d1bc0737898f28d4e1c17a99d5a3c71ada20873916d0d5d75a92db2aaab37b8a14a18338b7b223727f5d417"
            },
            "sequence": 4294967295
        },
        {
            "txid": "a97685efbed249543f34c22480609ea1851b4d4c76f7207db3de64b65206d037",
            "vout": 2,
            "scriptSig": {
                "asm": "30450221009ba99d89a15ccd7cefb499c42c0d94ed5e41a18d11007ba6d9d3edd479ec20bb02206c002e270c17190ab5f8d7fef33a73509aea518fae2671e21cdb3aa8dedf53ce01 049a56e83820ad23350de1b1fa3b2686ef053c75c2a01dcae4e777e057e985aa94e8d2a5d7d158c970b10097249dcaa4ec34748f4402a5c4c8eb7a61a27cf3ba80",
                "hex": "4830450221009ba99d89a15ccd7cefb499c42c0d94ed5e41a18d11007ba6d9d3edd479ec20bb02206c002e270c17190ab5f8d7fef33a73509aea518fae2671e21cdb3aa8dedf53ce0141049a56e83820ad23350de1b1fa3b2686ef053c75c2a01dcae4e777e057e985aa94e8d2a5d7d158c970b10097249dcaa4ec34748f4402a5c4c8eb7a61a27cf3ba80"
            },
            "sequence": 4294967295
        },
        {
            "txid": "b4d9870feede32f52f15ec1c951f092ef895b70f7fc3c762d2b450a53366cfb6",
            "vout": 1,
            "scriptSig": {
                "asm": "3046022100cb5b6ba715d77876adcd39f5ecc315cd8bd79c29bb56970b9650603decd3f243022100ac157b1ccd55dc53afac81424d8bcadc371e70660659e4b1d2ac38dfd54e008601 0408ddf2624fcd9a76b6821768d901d136c72df5cfdeca960f698bbec2a24ce6fe65dc2795c4106db990f40674215c0badc15547749e1098ebf1acc23bfa164299",
                "hex": "493046022100cb5b6ba715d77876adcd39f5ecc315cd8bd79c29bb56970b9650603decd3f243022100ac157b1ccd55dc53afac81424d8bcadc371e70660659e4b1d2ac38dfd54e008601410408ddf2624fcd9a76b6821768d901d136c72df5cfdeca960f698bbec2a24ce6fe65dc2795c4106db990f40674215c0badc15547749e1098ebf1acc23bfa164299"
            },
            "sequence": 4294967295
        },
        {
            "txid": "19fb9c28502598ddb2940ac61e1425ca485bec9e8cb225dabb0d8d36e2525d40",
            "vout": 1,
            "scriptSig": {
                "asm": "3045022070d50be3affd2201bd8c7cf800c2610b4b1dc8b0edd3292c88b1a9abca272d69022100b60eef3992902992032087c51e6487115dd54ec35ecd75b0e83804f7dcc61a5d01 0403f8182f373e43770c0edcf5d793ec1e19d8600a4ef19d90860a5ed8ecd7fc445c4edb315e78db4a80f6aa2fe89e99a88e780bcf964af2b505abe7aefd2039c6",
                "hex": "483045022070d50be3affd2201bd8c7cf800c2610b4b1dc8b0edd3292c88b1a9abca272d69022100b60eef3992902992032087c51e6487115dd54ec35ecd75b0e83804f7dcc61a5d01410403f8182f373e43770c0edcf5d793ec1e19d8600a4ef19d90860a5ed8ecd7fc445c4edb315e78db4a80f6aa2fe89e99a88e780bcf964af2b505abe7aefd2039c6"
            },
            "sequence": 4294967295
        }
    ],
    "vout": [
        {
            "value": 0.01002,
            "n": 0,
            "scriptPubKey": {
                "asm": "OP_DUP OP_HASH160 0c32f2aac46ffdcc2f02048c5f18e1b24b9be3b1 OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG",
                "hex": "76a9140c32f2aac46ffdcc2f02048c5f18e1b24b9be3b188ac",
                "reqSigs": 1,
                "type": "pubkeyhash",
                "addresses": [
                    "127W9E5BVn6KxVCV2iiVbJmQrVoUd8xmu3"
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "value": 0.124,
            "n": 1,
            "scriptPubKey": {
                "asm": "OP_DUP OP_HASH160 4e900299bc94a699aef0fbf2dbbeabd3a3cb03e8 OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG",
                "hex": "76a9144e900299bc94a699aef0fbf2dbbeabd3a3cb03e888ac",
                "reqSigs": 1,
                "type": "pubkeyhash",
                "addresses": [
                    "18AQDxusBQTJiNSG6EszPUfi85RhDpo7Qf"
                ]
            }
        }
    ],
    "blockhash": "000000000000034a7dedef4a161fa058a2d67a173a90155f3a2fe6fc132e0ebf",
    "confirmations": 104243,
    "time": 1348310759,
    "blocktime": 1348310759
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Multisig transactions might have multiple `addresses`. For an example I found on [webbtc's list](http://webbtc.com/scripts/multisig) of multisig transactions, see [055f9c6dc094cf21fa224e1eb4a54ee3cc44ae9daa8aa47f98df5c73c48997f9](http://live.insight.is/api/tx/055f9c6dc094cf21fa224e1eb4a54ee3cc44ae9daa8aa47f98df5c73c48997f9) (using insight-api, since it's handy).

```
{
    "txid": "055f9c6dc094cf21fa224e1eb4a54ee3cc44ae9daa8aa47f98df5c73c48997f9",
    "version": 1,
    "locktime": 0,
    "vin": [
        {
            "txid": "b187426f2fdd5a7ac2f49d822f68e07f48486ee53a8a45de2494f12acb37a0d8",
            "vout": 3,
            "scriptSig": {
                "asm": "3046022100d78c31a20fa11533475be893b229eb4d252e600dcc2a0735d360c541b6aec813022100e3eaa72c915ef47d94ccbd18c2ba6d9ae5b98be6e9fbf968d4bbbb003e06d68701 030e001332b43924be343986cca3df669f57b0dedd120990e727787f8dea50fdbc"
            },
            "sequence": 4294967295,
            "n": 0,
            "addr": "1FrbMcddiM1v3HMpUqygjZYCamBykWCWao",
            "valueSat": 1114144,
            "value": 0.01114144,
            "doubleSpentTxID": null
        }
    ],
    "vout": [
        {
            "value": "0.00010860",
            "n": 0,
            "scriptPubKey": {
                "asm": "1 030e001332b43924be343986cca3df669f57b0dedd120990e727787f8dea50fdbc 20434e545250525459000000140001a9e0e85838b5000000174876e800010053b6 2 OP_CHECKMULTISIG",
                "reqSigs": 1,
                "type": "multisig",
                "addresses": [
                    "1FrbMcddiM1v3HMpUqygjZYCamBykWCWao",
                    "1HT7xU2Ngenf7D4yocz2SAcnNLW7rK8d4E"
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "value": "0.00010860",
            "n": 1,
            "scriptPubKey": {
                "asm": "1 030e001332b43924be343986cca3df669f57b0dedd120990e727787f8dea50fdbc 20a3c3000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 2 OP_CHECKMULTISIG",
                "reqSigs": 1,
                "type": "multisig",
                "addresses": [
                    "1FrbMcddiM1v3HMpUqygjZYCamBykWCWao",
                    "1HT7xU2Ngenf7D4yocz2SAcnNLW7rK8d4E"
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "value": "0.00010860",
            "n": 2,
            "scriptPubKey": {
                "asm": "1 030e001332b43924be343986cca3df669f57b0dedd120990e727787f8dea50fdbc 100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 2 OP_CHECKMULTISIG",
                "reqSigs": 1,
                "type": "multisig",
                "addresses": [
                    "1FrbMcddiM1v3HMpUqygjZYCamBykWCWao",
                    "1HT7xU2Ngenf7D4yocz2SAcnNLW7rK8d4E"
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "value": "0.01061564",
            "n": 3,
            "scriptPubKey": {
                "asm": "OP_DUP OP_HASH160 a2f2d251cc06ec1e789800127e3fa6ed9e515651 OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG",
                "reqSigs": 1,
                "type": "pubkeyhash",
                "addresses": [
                    "1FrbMcddiM1v3HMpUqygjZYCamBykWCWao"
                ]
            }
        }
    ],
    "blockhash": "0000000000000000491fdff68a1c99de7798278a791e461b8d5bebdd9df9de46",
    "confirmations": 1,
    "time": 1401911255,
    "blocktime": 1401911255,
    "valueOut": 0.01094144,
    "size": 433,
    "valueIn": 0.01114144,
    "fees": 0.0002
}
```

Comment: So when the script stored in the value of "asm" is run in the next transaction, it will verify the signatures of BOTH addresses? That's how I'm understanding it.

Comment: This particular example appears to be a "1-of-2" [multisig](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Script#Crypto), which means that either of the addresses can spend the coins. Blockchain.info calls this output an [escrow](https://blockchain.info/tx/055f9c6dc094cf21fa224e1eb4a54ee3cc44ae9daa8aa47f98df5c73c48997f9) (which probably means that's the most likely reason you'd do a 1-of-2 multisig).

Comment: If you look at transaction https://blockchain.info/tx/56214420a7c4dcc4832944298d169a75e93acf9721f00656b2ee0e4d194f9970, this has a 2 of 3 raw multisig address.